# IO handling for Child Interpreters in Tcl

Tags: tcl, stdout

While trying to work with child interpreters, i noticed that the below code is able to close stdout and then write to a file instead.

```
close stdout
set file [open log.txt w]
puts "hello" # prints it to a file
```

However, the same doesn't work for child interpreters though

```
interp create foo
foo eval {close stdout}
foo eval {set file [open log.txt w]}
foo eval {puts "hello"} #Error: can not find channel named "stdout"
```

I am trying to find a way that stdout is also not closed and output is also redirected to a file in a third party tool. What did i miss here?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the reason that the `close stdout;open` trick doesn't work in child interpreters is that the parent interpreter *also* has `stdout` open, so closing it in the child just makes the child lose access to it, it doesn't actually close the underlying file descriptor, and hence the OS doesn't open the new file descriptor in that slot.

You'd also see that effect if you used multiple threads. (Channels are reference-counted entities, and are very much thread-aware.)

There are two simple ways to handle the third-party tool:

1. Run the tool in a subprocess, when you have all the redirection tools in `exec` (or `open |…`).
2. Replace the `puts` command so that you can intercept writes *at the script level* and do the right thing.

   ```
    rename puts _real_puts
    proc puts args {
        global accumulator
        if {[llength $args] == 1} {
            append accumulator [lindex $args 1] "\n"
            return
        } elseif {[llength $args] == 2 && [lindex $args 1] eq "-nonewline"} {
            append accumulator [lindex $args 1]
            return
        }
        tailcall _real_puts {*}$args
    }
   ```

   You might need a bit more complexity than that if the tool explicitly uses `stdout`.

Intercepting writes to the Tcl `stdout` channel from the C level is possible, but requires something like [this](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/virtchannel_transform/observe.md).

Intercepting direct writes to the standard output file descriptor from the C level is normally not possible, and is certainly not easy. You'd need to mess around with the `dup()` and `dup2()` system calls.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have tried replacing the puts command but it doesn't work either, looks like i have to try intercepting it. I will go through the link you shared.